# Scrollbar Overly Sensitive on Ms Access using TeeChart

Tags: ms-access, activex, teechart

I am evaluating the Teechart ActiveX control on Ms Access and i am having a strange issue with the Axis Scrollbar.

While it seems to be working, it is overly sensitive to mouse movement. Just by moving the mouse, the scrollbar shift to the far left.

Clicking the body of the scrollbar (not the arrows) returns it to the view but this is not right.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce it with the example shipped with the installation at "Examples\MSOffice\VBA Access\Teedemo.accdb". Could you please arrange a [simple example project](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here?

Comment: I am afraid that SO makes it extra hard to attach a file but nothing special is here...just drop a TeeChart ..add a Candle Type chart..populate it with enough values and drop a Tools --> Other -->Axis Scrollbar...as the mouse pointer moves over the scrollbar the "magic" starts.

Comment: Do you observe the same behaviour with another series type or only with the Candle?